# Is it okay to continue workouts while fasting?

Tags: weightlifting, diet, cardio

I'm fasting (water only) for an undetermined amount of time (7-14 days) for personal reasons, but I want to continue my workouts so I don't fall out of the habit.  I'm afraid if I let myself skip them I won't restart right away, leading to months of inactivity - it's happened before!

Typically, I have 2-3 cardio workouts a week (30min to 1hr of running/cycling) and 2 weight lifting workouts (3x5 barbell squats, rows, et cetera)

What can I do to ensure safe workouts while I fast?  I'm considering modifying/cheating my fast to include milk on workout days, would this help with the weight lifting?  Or is this crazy and I should take a break from the exercise, too?

Comment: I have no expertise on this topic, but I'd at least dramatically reduce your weekly training volume during the fast. Half the training with reduced weights would be fine--you'll almost certainly loss strength and conditioning, but I'd be concerned with "bonking" if you don't.

Comment: What are your training goals? It's possible that your training time will be useless if you're not feeding yourself, and it may be better to just not do them.

Comment: My goal is to not fall out of the habit during a 1-2 week fast.

Comment: Then there's nothing wrong with workouts while fasting if your only goal is to be present for them, and have no volume or intensity goals.

Comment: Cool story.  I'll cut the weight, reduce the reps, and keep the runs short and easy.  Thanks.  If you want to make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do any heavy workouts while fasting. One time I had neglected to eat (not due to fasting, but due to being distracted) for a while before my workout and I miscalculated the weights I was lifting - increasing my previous max by 40lbs instead of just 10lbs. That was not good for my form.

For marathons I wouldn't really go more than 45 minutes between eating carbohydrate packs, unless I'd loaded up on quark in the morning.

If you were planning on doing a 40 day fast, I might suggest throwing in a couple weight lifting runs spaced 1-2 weeks apart, but even that probably isn't without risks. If you're only fasting for several days, up to a week, I'd just take a break from the workouts as well.

Comment: No heavy workouts for sure.  But what how should I change the workout for a fast somewhere in-between a week and 40 days?

Comment: @mebassett Do you normally do warmup sets?

Comment: @robin_Ashe indeed.  5 reps, 3 reps, 1 rep starting at roughly 50% and ending at roughly 90% of my workout weight.

Comment: @mebassett if I were doing that I think I'd stick to the first and second warmup sets, and just leave it at that. depending on the exercises you do, I might abbreviate the selection as well, down to 3 or 4.